# JavaScript - Find Occurrences of XX distance apart in Array

Tags: javascript

this one is a little past my capabilities at the moment and welcome some guidance.

Challenge:

I have a hairdresser with available timeslots as per below, all slots are 30 mins in length nb.timeslots are INT.

depending on what the customer needs they could book up to 4 slots in a row.
I need to display to the customer the timeslots that are available for booking based on whatever product they select. i.e just first slot.

```
in this example the stylist is not available 11am and 1:30pm thus remove from the below.
const exampleArray = [
{id: 1, Timeslot: 480, displayText: '8am'},
{id: 2, Timeslot: 510, displayText: '8:30am'},
{id: 3, Timeslot: 540, displayText: '9am'},
{id: 4, Timeslot: 570, displayText: '9:30am'},
{id: 5, Timeslot: 600, displayText: '10am'},
{id: 6, Timeslot: 630, displayText: '10:30am'},
{id: 7, Timeslot: 690, displayText: '11:30am'},
{id: 8, Timeslot: 720, displayText: '12pm'},
{id: 9, Timeslot: 750, displayText: '12:30pm'},
{id: 10, Timeslot: 780, displayText: '1pm'},
{id: 11, Timeslot: 840, displayText: '2pm'},
{id: 12, Timeslot: 870, displayText: '2:30pm'},
{id: 13, Timeslot: 900, displayText: '3pm'},
{id: 14, Timeslot: 930, displayText: '3:30pm'},
.....and so on
}]
```

as example customer wants haircut lasting 2 hours, then I need to return each block of 4 hours avlb, but on top i also need to nest the id numbers of the the avlb slots as i'll use this to amend the DB:

```
[
{id: 1, Timeslot: 480, displayText: '8am', linkedIds:[1,2,3,4]},
{id: 2, Timeslot: 510, displayText: '8:30am', linkedIds:[2,3,4,5]},
{id: 3, Timeslot: 540, displayText: '9am', linkedIds:[3,4,5,6]},
{id: 7, Timeslot: 690, displayText: '11:30am', linkedIds:[7,8,9,10]},
{id: 11, Timeslot: 840, displayText: '2pm', linkedIds:[11,12,13,14]},
]
```

i started with the following pretty basic code, primarily to allow me to get the DB interaction functional, but now i have revisited the code I don't know how to scale it from what it is to something more eloquent and something that doesn't rely on a silly amount of 'if' statements.

```
let result =[]
const arr = exampleArray //array described above

//logic here was for 2 slots being booked
    for (let i = 0, x = 1; x < arr.length; i++, x++) {

        if (
            arr[i].timeslot ===
            arr[x].timeslot - 30
        ) {
            let temp = {
                id: arr[i].id,
                timeslot: arr[i].timeslot,
                linkedIds: [arr[i].id, arr[x].id],
                displayText: arr[i].displayText
            }
            result.push(temp) //creates one compiled list for screen render
        } 
    }
```

i guessing i need to utilise filter and map to get to end result but struggling to get my head around it tbh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution. I modified it to be more flexible and handle any number of time blocks.

```
const exampleArray = [
    {id: 1, Timeslot: 480, displayText: '8am'},
    {id: 2, Timeslot: 510, displayText: '8:30am'},
    {id: 3, Timeslot: 540, displayText: '9am'},
    {id: 4, Timeslot: 570, displayText: '9:30am'},
    {id: 5, Timeslot: 600, displayText: '10am'},
    {id: 6, Timeslot: 630, displayText: '10:30am'},
    //{id: 7, Timeslot: 690, displayText: '11:30am'},
    //{id: 8, Timeslot: 720, displayText: '12pm'},
    //{id: 9, Timeslot: 750, displayText: '12:30pm'},
    {id: 10, Timeslot: 780, displayText: '1pm'},
    {id: 11, Timeslot: 840, displayText: '2pm'},
    {id: 12, Timeslot: 870, displayText: '2:30pm'},
    {id: 13, Timeslot: 900, displayText: '3pm'},
    {id: 14, Timeslot: 930, displayText: '3:30pm'}
};

//arr - The array of available time slots.
//blockSize - The number of time slots in a block
function getAvailability(arr, blockSize){
    let result = []

    //How much to offset from 0 index.
    const offset = blockSize - 1;

    //If there is less than 4 spaces in the loop, no test needed to be done. 
    const len = arr.length - offset;

    for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {

        //Assuming that timeslots are all in order and have 30 minute increments, and unavailable times are removed from array, the offset timeslot should have a timeslot difference of the blockSize times the 30 minutes.
        if (arr[i].timeslot === arr[i + offset].timeslot - 30 * blockSize) {
        
            let temp = {
                id: arr[i].id,
                timeslot: arr[i].timeslot,
                linkedIds: [],
                displayText: arr[i].displayText
            }
            
            //Get all id's for the the number of blocks required.
            for (let x = i; i < blockSize; x++) {
                temp.linkedIds.push(arr[x].id);
            }
            
            result.push(temp) //creates one compiled list for screen render
        } 
    }

    return result;
}

//Usage:

getAvailability(exampleArray, 4);
```

Comment: perfect thanks so much, i had to change 2 parts, in the first if statement changed blocksize to offset; by using block size we were trying to count 5 blocks instead of 4. and in the linkedIds loop amended as follows for (let x = i; x < blockSize + i; x++)

Answer (score 1):

I coded up a solution that I think works well, as you mentioned using `map` and `filter`.

```
function getTimeslotsOfDuration(exampleArray, numslots) {
  // map the array to only timeslots for ease of use
  let timeslotArray = exampleArray.map(e => e.Timeslot);
  let res = exampleArray.filter((e) => {
    for (i = 1; i < numslots; i++) {
      if (!timeslotArray.includes(e.Timeslot + i * 30)) {
        // one of the 4 slots is unavailable!
        return false;
      }
    }
    // if we reach this point, all slots are available for this starting slot
    return true;
  });
  return res;
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, really helps me understand the logic and how to use in the future. I did in the end give rbrundritt as correct answer, but purely because he captured the need for nested linkedIds.  thanks